# how can i get dynamic named parameters in Parent method c#

Tags: c#

I just want to get child parameters values and names in a parent class method

```
class Base
{
    public dynamic get(//how can i get child class parameters)
    {
        // do something
    }
}

class User:Base
{
    public int id {get;set}
    public string name {get;set}
    public string password {get;set}
    this.get( id = 5,name = "admin", password = "admin")
}

class Task:Base
{
    public int id {get;set}
    public string name {get;set}
    this.get(id=1,name="task1")
}
```

I already tried with params dynamic[] values but in this case I'm getting only values but I also want names.
Can anyone guide me how can I achieve this?.

Comment: You are doing something wrong if your base class needs to know its children.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a XY problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem

````
{
    public object get(params Func<object, object>[] args)
    {
        // do something
    }
}

class User:Base
{
    public int id {get;set}
    public string name {get;set}
    public string password {get;set}
    this.get( id => 5,name => "admin", password => "admin")
}

class Task:Base
{
    public int id {get;set}
    public string name {get;set}
    this.get(id=>1,name=>"task1")
}```
````